# Putting related static functions in a class

Tags: python

Let's say I have three functions for visualizing data:

```
def visulizeFoo():
    do something
def visualizeBar():
    do something
def plotFooBar():
    do something
```

Is it pythonic to combine them under a common class, even though they do not share any variables and can be easily implemented as separate functions?

```
class Visualizations(object):
    @staticmethod
    def visulizeFoo():
        do something
    @staticmethod
    def visualizeBar():
        do something
    @staticmethod
    def plotFooBar():
        do something
```

Does using @staticmethod in such a way make sense? What if all the member functions in this class are static? Is there an established style?

One might argue it is more orderly to call visualizeFoo() in the following fashion:

```
Visualizations().visualizeFoo()
```

Comment: In that case putting these in a module seems to make more sense I think, modules can be imported, and then you can call functions with `module.function(some, parameters)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Makes perfect sense. Thanks!